# Backbone view has wrong el

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am storing all file uploads in progress, FileUploadProgressModel, on a Backbone collection, UploadProgressCollection. I have everything working except the `this.$el` on my view, UploadPrograssView. I have initialized the `$el` to `<body>` tag of my page.

I want `this.$el` to be the body element of my HTML page, instead it has a brand new `<body>` HTMLElement. Now I can not access my upload progress bar element using `this.$el` since `this.$el` is not the `<body>` tag I want. What causes this error?

```
var FileUploadProgressModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        this.on("change:loaded_size", function(){
            this.set("progress", 100 * this.get("loaded_size") / this.get("total_size"));
        });
    },
    defaults : {
        progress : 0,
        total_size: 1,
        loaded_size : 0,

    }
});
var UploadProgressCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FileUploadProgressModel,
    initialize : function(){
    this.on("update", function(){
        // View already registered to this event
    });
},
});


var UploadPrograssView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    tagName : "body",
    initialize : function(){
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    render : function(){

        var total_loaded_size = 0;
        var total_file_upload_size = 0;
        tracker.forEach(function(model){
            if(!isNaN(model.get("loaded_size"))) total_loaded_size += model.get("loaded_size");
            if(!isNaN(model.get("total_size"))) total_file_upload_size += model.get("total_size");
        });

        var progress = parseInt(total_loaded_size / total_file_upload_size * 100, 10) + '%';

        //TODO bad way of doing things. I want to user this.$el but it has lost the actual referance to the body instread it has this new HTML element "<body><body>"
        $('.progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress
                );
        return this;
    }
});


var tracker = new UploadProgressCollection();
var trackerView = new UploadPrograssView({model : tracker });
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to make the `<body>` tag itself as the view. Clearing the view will probably clear everything such as scripts tags, stuff injected by plugins etc. Add containers inside `<body>` and manipulate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **explicitly** specify `el` property for your View if you want the view to reference an element already existing in the DOM. If `tagName` property is specified, a **new** element is created. See [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) for more details.

So you have to set `el` to DOM selector string when you declare a View:

```
var UploadPrograssView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    el: "body",
    ...
});
```

Comment: Their API is so rich, to bad I didn't look pass the download button before. Was following a Book to learn. This works. Thanks